# AngularJS: Why is my directive's link function not being called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am using [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput) and would like to perform some validation on my models as they change. [Here is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nM1SohRT6cLIvzPaGBgy?p=preview) of what I'd like to achieve.

Markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <tags-input ng-model="field.selectedData" max-tags="{{field.maxTags}}" enforce-max-tags placeholder="{{option.placeholder}}">
          <auto-complete source="updateAutocomplete($query)"></auto-complete>
     </tags-input>
</div>
```

Fields / models:

```
$scope.fields = [
    {
        name: 'assay',
        placeholder: 'Select one assay...',
        maxTags: 1,
        selectedData: [] // These are the models
    },
    {
        name: 'cellLines',
        placeholder: 'Select cell line(s)...',
        maxTags: 5,
        selectedData: []
    },
    ...
]
```

Finally, my `enforceMaxTags` directive:

```
.directive('enforceMaxTags', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                console.log('link called');
            });
        }
    };
})
```

The `enforceMaxTags` directive is being compiled, but the `link` function is not called even when the models change. The data binding does appear to work, though, because if I `console.log` the `selectedData` on form submission, it is filled with the correct objects. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post a Plunker with the code that isn't working?

Comment: Seems working. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/z68cu233/)

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle @themyth92. It is a versioning issue; I'm using Angular 1.3.15 instead of Angular 1.2.24.